# Facebook like feeds view with listview and table view android

Tags: android, listview, tableview, listviewitem

I am trying to develop a facebook kind of feeds using list view and table view. Each row has the feed post with comments in the list view. I am storing the data objects of feed in the array list. My data object structure is as follows

```
class FeedPost{
    String username;
    String imageUrl;
    String feedpostText;
    ArrayList<Comment> comments;}
```

The comment class looks like this

```
class Comment{
     String imageUrl;
    String username;
    String Text;
    }
```

Now I will display the data with the itemview table layout. This is something like below.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/FeedTableLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/feed_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <TextView android:id="@+id/FeedPostusername"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/FeedPostText"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

The above block of code is the item layout in the listview. This shows the main feed content. Now to show the comments to the feed. I have another layout with different design and image. The sample layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/feed_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/CommentPic"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/Commentusername"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/CommentText"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

All the data regarding the feeds and comments are stored in the main arraylist

```
ArrayList<FeedPost> TotalFeed = new ArrayList<FeedPost>();
```

I use a custom list adapter to show the contents of the arraylist of total feeds. Since each feed has various comments count, I use a loop to manually add the comment to the table layout by inflating the comment layout.

So my getview() in the adapter will be like this

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    feedItem = FeedItems.get(position);

   convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_main, null);
   TableLayout mainFeedLayout = (TableLayout) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.blogFeedTableLayout);

   TextView displayName = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.feed_username);
   TextView description = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.comment_text);

  // Set the text to the texview
           .
           .
           .

  // Adding comments to the feed
  for (int i = 0; i < feedItem.feedComments.size(); i++) {
      mainFeedLayout .addView(addComment(
     convertView, feedItem.feedComments.get(i)));
     }

 }
```

The addcomment is the function which is used to add the comments to the feed

```
private View addComment(View view, Comment comment) {
    View commentLayout = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.comment, null);


        ImageView pic = (ImageView) commentLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.pic);
        TextView userName = (TextView) commentLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.comment_username);
        TextView commentText = (TextView) commentLayout
    }
```

So for a single feed to be displayed in the list view, I am checking the each feed item for comments and displaying them in the feed. This is really painful and slow.

I tried using the static holders for layouts instead of inflating them each time. Again that didnt work also. If there are mulitple different views, then i would have tried "SackOfViewsAdapter " of commonsguy. But actually it is not different views.

I think facebook uses the webview and render the html for the showing the feeds of the user. What is the best way to do the same using the android native layout and code. Can you help me in suggesting the best method to use for showing this kind of complex data?